# Flutter CircularPercentIndicator percentage from async call

Tags: dart, async-await, flutter

So I have a circular percent indicator on my app, which works fine if I hard code a value in there.

```
CircularPercentIndicator(
    radius: 60.0,
    lineWidth: 5.0,
    percent:0.2,
    center: new Text("35%"),
    progressColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    footer: new Text(
    "Food container status",
    style:
    new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
    ),
)
```

The problem is that I want that value to come from an async call to an web API. The percent field expects a double, but my call returns a Future double.

```
CircularPercentIndicator(
    radius: 60.0,
    lineWidth: 5.0,
    percent: feedingRepository.getContainerPercent(),//returns Future<double>,expects double
    center: new Text("35%"),
    progressColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    footer: new Text(
    "Food container status",
    style:
    new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17.0),
    ),
)
```

Is there a work around this thing or do I need to write a circular percent indicator myself?

Comment: *Is there a work around this thing* - wrap your CirclePercentIndicator in a FutureBuilder<double> and show the CirclePercentIndicator when you receive the double value.

Comment: That did the trick @Luksprog. Thanks